# SQL: select column from same table

Tags: mysql, sql

how to select from database to show this new table into page. I'm just select from the same table. Can anyone help this?

#### Original Table from db

```
Id | Username | UserType | SpecialId
-------------------------------------
1  | jdoe     | Type_A   | SP_1
2  | dmatt    | Type_A   | SP_2
3  | kwill    | Type_A   | SP_3
4  | kwill_a  | Type_B   | SP_3
5  | dmatt_a  | Type_B   | SP_2
6  | dmatt_b  | Type_B   | SP_2
```

#### New table

```
No | Type_A Username | Type_B Username
-------------------------------------
1  | jdoe            | -
2  | dmatt           | dmatt_a, dmatt_b
3  | kwill           | kwill_a
```

Comment: How many types are there? is it fixed?

Comment: Only got 2 type. Type_A & Type_B

Comment: Are these same user? `dmatt_a`, `dmatt_b` and `dmat`?

Comment: Nope, they all are different user, more like nested user (`dmatt_a` & `dmatt_b`) under this main user (`dmatt`).

Comment: So, who are the main users? Do they follow any pattern like having a name without `underscore` or something like that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you may want to do this(Looks like a table pivot issue):

```
select
    replace(SpecialId, 'SP_', '') as No,
    max(case when UserType = 'Type_A' then UserName else '-' end) as Type_A_UserName,
    max(case when UserType = 'Type_B' then UserName else '-' end) as Type_B_UserName
from (
  select `UserType`, `SpecialId`, group_concat(UserName) as UserName
  from yourtable
  group by `UserType`, `SpecialId`) t
group by SpecialId
```

[<kbd>SqlFiddle Demo</kbd>](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/992772/7)

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
SELECT a.id, a.username, GROUP_CONCAT(b.username)
 FROM (SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE usertype='Type_A') AS a
  LEFT JOIN (SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE usertype='Type_B') AS b
    ON a.specialid = b.specialid
```

This achieves the objective by combining a sub query with a self join.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
    ifnull(tabA.UsernameA, '-') AS UsernameA, 
    ifnull(tabB.UsernameB, '-') AS UsernameB
FROM (
    SELECT SpecialId, group_concat(Username) AS UsernameA
    FROM tab
    WHERE UserType = 'Type_A'
    GROUP BY 1
) AS tabA
OUTER JOIN (
    SELECT SpecialId, group_concat(Username) AS UsernameB
    FROM tab
    WHERE UserType = 'Type_B'
    GROUP BY 1
) AS tabB ON tabA.SpecialId = tabB.SpecialId
```